# Ayuda para escribir en la salida. stdin.readLineSync

Tags: dart, input, keyboard

¡Saludos! Estoy empezando a aprender dart desde cero, nunca he programado, así que todavía estoy muy verde en la terminología, perdonen la forma de expresarme, pero bueno vamos avanzando. Ya he hecho algunos programillas sencillitos y cada vez voy aprendiendo mas funciones.

En el que estoy ahora quiero interactuar con la salida de la consola, escribir en ella y que según lo escrito me lleve a un sitio o a otro. Concretamente quiero que me 'pida' que cálculo quiero hacer de tres opciones que le doy y una vez escrito el tipo de cálculo que me 'pida' los datos. Los tres cálculos que he desarrollado son los siguientes:

```
main() {
  print ('calcular el área de un rectangulo');
  //meter los datos en 'base' y 'altura'
  int base= 22;
  int altura = 3;
  int area=base*altura;
  print('El área del cuadrilátero es $area'); 

  print ('calcular el perímetro de un círculo');
  //meter los datos en 'r'
  final double pi = 3.14;
  double r=30;
  double per=2*pi*r;
  print ('El perímetro del círculo es $per');

  //meter los datos en 'kg'
  print('Pasar kilogramos a gramos');
  double kg=3;
  double gramos=kg*1000;
  print('$kg kg son $gramos gramos');

}
```

He encontrado stdin.readLineSync para escribir donde quiero y con este ejemplo:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  print('print something');
  String a=stdin.readLineSync();
  print ('you typed in $a ');

}
```

pero no consigo interactuar con 'a' más allá de lo establecido en el ejemplo, por que si después escribo en el código algo como  `if(a==25){}`, y le pongo la condición que sea, al escribir luego 25 en el terminal 25 ignora la condición.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a entender como funciona `stdin.readLineSync` con algun ejemplo que interactúe mas allá del establecido arriba? Gracias de antemano.

Edito: Ya he conseguido hacerlo:

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(){

  //meter los datos en 'base' y 'altura'
  int base= 22;
  int altura = 3;
  int area=base*altura;


  //meter los datos en 'r'
  final double pi = 3.14;
  double r=30;
  double per=2*pi*r;


  //meter los datos en 'kg'
  print('Pasar kilogramos a gramos');
  double kg=3;
  double gramos=kg*1000;


  print('''¿Qué cálculo quieres hacer?
  Escribe 'area' para hallar el área de un rectángulo.
  Escribe 'perimetro' para hallar el perímetro de un circulo.
  Escribe 'gramos' para pasar de kg a gr.''');
  String a=stdin.readLineSync();

  if(a=='area'){
  print('El área del cuadrilátero es $area');}

  if(a=='perimetro'){
  print ('El perímetro del círculo es $per');}  

   if(a=='gramos'){
  print('$kg kg son $gramos gramos');}

}
```

El problema ahora es que ahora que ya lo dirijo al cálculo que quiero no consigo hacer lo mismo con los datos del cálculo, por que para meter los datos que serían tipo numéricos no lo reconocen como tal, stdin.readLineSync solo te deja meterlos como String ¿Alguna idea?

edito2: Conseguido al fin, dejo el código por si a alguien que esté empezando como yo le sirve de ejemplo:

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(){


 print('''¿Qué cálculo quieres hacer?
  Escribe 'area' para hallar el área de un rectángulo.
  Escribe 'perimetro' para hallar el perímetro de un circulo.
  Escribe 'gramos' para pasar de kg a gr.''');
  String a=stdin.readLineSync();

    switch (a){
      case'area':
       print('valor lado 1');
    var b= stdin.readLineSync();
    print('valor lado 2');
    var c= stdin.readLineSync();
    var lado1 = int.parse('$b');
    var lado2 = int.parse('$c');
    int area=lado1*lado2;
  print('El área del cuadrilátero es $area');
      ;
      break;
       case 'perimetro':print('valor del radio del círculo');
    var d= stdin.readLineSync();

    var r = double.parse('$d');
    final double pi = 3.14;  
    double per=2*pi*r;
  print ('El perímetro del círculo es $per');

      break;
       case 'gramos':
       print('introduce los kilogramos');
    var e= stdin.readLineSync();    
    var kg = double.parse('$e');    
    double gramos=kg*1000;     
  print('$kg kg son $gramos gramos');
     break;

    default:
      print('Cálculo no posible');
      String a=stdin.readLineSync();


do { print('Cálculo no posible');
     String a=stdin.readLineSync();
     if(a=='perimetro'){
    print('valor del radio del círculo');
    var d= stdin.readLineSync();

    var r = double.parse('$d');
    final double pi = 3.14;  
    double per=2*pi*r;
  print ('El perímetro del círculo es $per');
  break;}

  if(a=='area'){
    print('valor lado 1');
    var b= stdin.readLineSync();
    print('valor lado 2');
    var c= stdin.readLineSync();
    var lado1 = int.parse('$b');
    var lado2 = int.parse('$c');
    int area=lado1*lado2;
  print('El área del cuadrilátero es $area');
  break;}

    if(a=='gramos'){
    print('introduce los kilogramos');
    var e= stdin.readLineSync();    
    var kg = double.parse('$e');    
    double gramos=kg*1000;     
  print('$kg kg son $gramos gramos');
  break;}  

      }
while(a!='area'||a!='perimetro'||a!='gramos');
      }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta utilizar lo siguiente en tu código:

```dart
stdout.write('''¿Qué cálculo quieres hacer?
  Escribe 'area' para hallar el área de un rectángulo.
  Escribe 'perimetro' para hallar el perímetro de un circulo.
  Escribe 'gramos' para pasar de kg a gr.''');
String a = stdin.readLineSync().toString();
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].